# How to move std::ostringstream's underlying string object?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
string ToString(const T& obj)
{
    ostringstream oss;
    oss << obj;

    //
    // oss will never be used again, so I should
    // MOVE its underlying string.
    //
    // However, below will COPY, rather than MOVE, 
    // oss' underlying string object!
    //
    return oss.str();
}
```

**How to move std::ostringstream's underlying string object?**

Comment: I guess you could do it by `s = move( oss.rdbuf()->str() )` [ Oh, I checked, **you can't**], but you risk breaking the assumptions of the stream code by pulling the rug from under its feet.*. Why do you want this?

Comment: I think you can invent something interesting using `node handle` from C++17: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/node_handle

Comment: This isn't possible, there's no obligation that a `std::basic_stringbuf` uses a `std::basic_string` as its underlying buffer (even though this is how it's done in practice).

Comment: @user657267: It <del>does</del> APPEARS TO have a string as buffer, that's what the [`str` member functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringbuf/str) are all about. But it doesn't provide mutable access to it. Hm.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf If that were the case then the class description would have an "exposition only" private `std::basic_string` member, the standard only refers to an "underlying character sequence".

Comment: Move oss, and then in external code get string?

Comment: There is no requirement on `stringstream` to store the data  in contiguious buffer AFAIK. So, to get the string, you will have to construct a string object atleast once.

Comment: I know of two implementations that use a `basic_string` and one that uses a plain `char` array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard says that [`std::ostringstream::str()` returns a *copy*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/str).

One way to avoid this copy is to implement another `std::streambuf` derived-class that exposes the string buffer directly. Boost.IOStreams makes this pretty trivial:

```
#include <boost/iostreams/stream_buffer.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace io = boost::iostreams;

struct StringSink
{
    std::string string;

    using char_type = char;
    using category = io::sink_tag;

    std::streamsize write(char const* s, std::streamsize n) {
        string.append(s, n);
        return n;
    }
};

template<typename T>
std::string ToString(T const& obj) {
    io::stream_buffer<StringSink> buffer{{}};

    std::ostream stream(&buffer);
    stream << obj;
    stream.flush();

    return std::move(buffer->string); // <--- Access the string buffer directly here and move it.
}

int main() {
    std::cout << ToString(3.14) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: This *copies* the string also, because ``buffer->string`` is neither a prvalue, nor a temporary, nor does it meet the requirements for copy elision of being the name of a non-volatile object of automatic storage duration (and of the same type as returned). In this case, you *have* to force a move using e.g. ``std::move``. Since ``buffer->string`` cannot possibly be eligible for copy elision in any case, this doesn't prevent other optimizations.

Comment: @ArneVogel You are right that there is another copy operation here. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Since C++20 you can.

```
std::move(oss).str()
```